# Can we push and pop both at a single transition in a PDA?

Tags: pushdown-automata

Let say I have a pda :

δ(q1,a,Z)=(q2,aZ)

δ(q2,a,aZ)=(q2,bZ)

Is this allowed....

you can see that in **δ(q2,a,aZ)=(q2,bZ)**, we are basically popping 'a' and pushing 'b' for a single transition...

Is this allowed for PDA ??

Comment: If the question is "can a PDA transition simply replace the top element of the stack instead of removing it or adding something", then the answer is "yes".

Comment: @G. Bach Yep.. That's what i was looking for... 
Thanks...

Comment: @Patrick87 make this to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Previously a comment)

Depends on how you define PDAs. The definition I consider canonical certainly does allow you to exactly this: it is assumed that each transition pops the top-most symbol, and pushes an arbitrary string. To represent not changing the stack, you'd push the same symbol you just popped; to pop one symbol, you'd push the empty string; to put $w$ on top of the stack, you'd push $wa$ (where $a$ is the top-most symbol); and to replace $a$ with $b$, you'd push $b$.